How to get all products related to chain of tags?
I have two tables:
// tags
+----+-----------------------+-----------+
| id |         name          | parent_id |
+----+-----------------------+-----------+
| 1  | Home                  | Null      |
| 2  | Kitchen               | 1         |
| 3  | Serving and reception | 2         |
| 4  | Spoon                 | 3         |
| 5  | Digital               | NULL      |
| 6  | Communication         | 5         |
| 7  | Cellphone             | 6         |
+----+-----------------------+-----------+

// products
+----+------------------------------------------+--------+
| id |                name                      | tag_id | -- this is the deepest tag id
+----+------------------------------------------+--------+
| 1  | Dinner Spoon Set,16 Pcs 7.3" Tablespoons | 4      | 
| 2  | iPhone 14 Promax                         | 7      |
| 3  | Samsung A20                              | 7      |
+----+------------------------------------------+--------+

I need to implement a products listing page per "tag". So, I need to get
| 2  | iPhone 14 Promax                         | 7      |
| 3  | Samsung A20                              | 7      |

by passing each of the following tags.ids: 5, 6, 7 (since they are all related to that products)
Any idea how can I do that?
Real data simplified fiddle

Here is my current query: (the problem is it returns just one product, not a list of products)
WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, name, parent_id, orig_id) AS (
    SELECT id, name, parent_id, id AS orig_id
    FROM tags
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.parent_id, t2.orig_id
    FROM tags t1
    INNER JOIN cte t2
        ON t2.id = t1.parent_id
)

SELECT MAX(p.name) AS name
FROM cte t
LEFT JOIN products p
    ON p.tag_id = t.id
GROUP BY t.orig_id
HAVING SUM(t.id = 6) > 0;


What is the expected input/output for the data in the fiddle?

@Dogbert The expected result is a list of products related to the passed tag id .. tags are hierarchy, so, if a product has tag_id = 10, and that tag has a parent, then the product still must be selected if the passed tag id is the parent

in your cte, start by selecting the tag your query is for, then recursively find its children.  so if you start with tag 5, your cte gives 7, 6, and 5.  then just do a straightforward join of products to the cte tag.

See example



id
name
description
parent_id
status
created_at
updated_at




1
Home
null
null
active
2024-08-18 21:33:36
2024-08-18 21:33:36


2
Kitchen
null
1
active
2024-08-18 21:33:36
2024-08-18 21:33:36


3
Serving and reception
null
2
active
2024-08-18 21:33:36
2024-08-18 21:33:36


4
Spoon
null
3
active
2024-08-18 21:33:36
2024-08-18 21:33:36


5
Digital
null
null
active
2024-08-18 21:33:36
2024-08-18 21:33:36


6
Communication
null
5
active
2024-08-18 21:33:36
2024-08-18 21:33:36


7
Cellphone
null
6
active
2024-08-18 21:33:36
2024-08-18 21:33:36






id
name
tag_id




1
Dinner Spoon Set,16 Pcs 7.3" Tablespoons
4


2
iPhone 14 Promax
7


3
Samsung A20
7



WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, name, parent_id, orig_id) AS (
    SELECT id, name, parent_id, id AS orig_id
    FROM tags
    WHERE id=7 -- start tag
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.parent_id, t2.orig_id
    FROM tags t1
    INNER JOIN cte t2
        ON t2.id = t1.parent_id
)
SELECT p.*,t.*
FROM cte t
inner JOIN products p
    ON p.tag_id = t.id




id
name
tag_id
id
name
parent_id
orig_id




2
iPhone 14 Promax
7
7
Cellphone
6
7


3
Samsung A20
7
7
Cellphone
6
7



fiddle
OR with your data
fiddle
Recursive query output (3 levels), before (inner) join with product



id
name
tag_id
id
name
parent_id
orig_id




null
null
null
10
Mobile and accessories
2
10


24
Redmi Note 13 4G
47
47
mobile phone
10
10


14
Redmi A3 mobile phone
47
47
mobile phone
10
10


13
Redmi Note 13 Pro 4G
47
47
mobile phone
10
10


12
Redmi mobile phone 12
47
47
mobile phone
10
10


11
Samsung Galaxy S24 ultra mobile phone
47
47
mobile phone
10
10


10
Apple iPhone 13 CH
47
47
mobile phone
10
10


9
Samsung Galaxy A15 mobile phone
47
47
mobile phone
10
10


8
Redmi mobile phone 13C
47
47
mobile phone
10
10


7
Xiaomi Poco X6 Pro 5G
47
47
mobile phone
10
10


6
Samsung Galaxy A55 mobile phone
47
47
mobile phone
10
10


5
Xiaomi Poco C65 mobile phone
47
47
mobile phone
10
10


4
Samsung Galaxy S23 Fe mobile phone
47
47
mobile phone
10
10


3
Samsung A05 mobile phone
47
47
mobile phone
10
10


1
Samsung A35 mobile phone
47
47
mobile phone
10
10


null
null
null
48
mobile accessories
10
10


null
null
null
49
mobile parts
10
10



However, your test data does not include product rows at intermediate levels of the hierarchy. Try to enter such data for verification.
In your query part is unnecessary
GROUP BY t.orig_id
HAVING SUM(t.id = 6) > 0;

Enough
WHERE id=6 -- start tag

in anchor.

Per my comment above, I suspect they don't actually have intermediate levels, so don't really need recursion. Although this does allow for adding multiple levels later.

I can't say anything about the number of levels. There are at least 3 of them in the given data (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p7BRJDSYB3wSA36Yg1TNyS/0) or (https://dbfiddle.uk/ZD1cUNkp).

Ah right. They just don't have products in intermediate levels, only at the leaves.

Yes, it is. I think, however, intermediate levels should also be tested by OP.
